# Error with adding function in to dictionary (c#)

Tags: c#, dictionary, func

I'm trying to add function in to dictionary.
This works fine:

```
// public string GetDensity_EdgeZone_LeftHand()
Dictionary<string, Func<string>> FunctionsGetMeasureData;
FunctionsGetMeasureData = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>();
FunctionsGetMeasureData.Add(tempArea, _MeasureData.GetDensity_EdgeZone_LeftHand);
```

But, also in this `_MeasureData` i have 
`public Dictionary<eMeasureProperty, cClassifyData> MeasuresData;` and `cClassifyData` contains function `public string GetAverage(string classify)`

So, when I'm trying to add it like this:

```
FunctionsGetMeasureData.Add(tempArea, _MeasuresData.MeasuresData[NameKey].GetAverage(somename);
```

It all goes to hell. Wheres is problem? I also tryed to work with other type of dictionary `Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>> FunctionsGetComplexMeasureData`; Did not work too.

Comment: "It all goes to hell"? Please provide error messages or something descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not trying to add a function, you're adding the result of that function:

```
FunctionsGetMeasureData.Add(tempArea, _MeasuresData.MeasuresData[NameKey].GetAverage(somename));
```

If you want to add the function, you shouldn't invoke it:

```
FunctionsGetMeasureData.Add(tempArea, _MeasuresData.MeasuresData[NameKey].GetAverage);
```

Apart from that, if your dictionary is `Dictionary<string, Func<string>>` you can't add `_MeasuresData.MeasuresData[NameKey].GetAverage` because it's a `Func<string, string>`